# How to make start number when new row and insert new "Id"?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

*I Have Code Autonumber *

```
Sub AutoCount()
        Dim daC As New SqlDataAdapter("select Max(couttime) From TbCourse where cusid='" & txtcustomerid.Text & "' ", conn)
        Dim dsC As New DataSet
        daC.Fill(dsC, "Course")
        dsC.Tables(0).Clear()
        daC.Fill(dsC, "Course")
        txtcounttime.Text = Format(CInt(dsC.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)) + 1, "0")
    End Sub
```

And I have Table Ex:

[image]

Comment: How are the columns ordered?  You can use a rank in sql server to do this, but you need to order

Comment: i have oder already

Answer (score 0):

You need to check, is there any entry for the given `cusid`, if not it will return 1 (0 in case if you are +1 in the code), if the given `cusid` exists, it will return the MAX value for the `cusid`

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT cusid FROM TbCourse WHERE cusid = 'COL2')
    SELECT 1 AS couttime
ELSE
    SELECT MAX(couttime) AS couttime FROM TbCourse WHERE cusid = 'COL2'
```

Here `COL2` is the `txtcustomerid.Text` value.